# Frequent and persistent DNS failures

Tags: networking, dns, 17.04, systemd

Whenever I'm on a network that is anything less than rock solid (any packet loss, pretty much anything except cable ethernet) my Ubuntu 17.04 suffers from frequent DNS issues. Not only does it fail to resolve a name but also caches that and then fails to resolve the same name until I restart the local DNS service

```
systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

or just change the server to Google's 8.8.8.8 in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

It seems that the local resolver caches failures instead of retrying when faced with less-than-perfect connection.

**How can I improve the resilience of the DNS service or disable it completely?**

Comment: It's not a good practice to depend exclusively on an external DNS. You should set google DNS as secondary, but a local DNS (router, if you prefer) should be set as primary, so you will get more stability to your network.